# How to get the number of classes that have attributes in sparql

Tags: sparql, rdf, owl, semantic-web, rdfs

I am looking for a query in sparql language that will return the number of classes that have attributes (I think object properties are the attributes) - does anyone have an idea?

I am using this website -> http://139.91.210.25:8890/sparql to run my queries and I use this dataset name http://localhost:8890/pizza. Thank you very much

Comment: What have you tried? On StackOverflow, the way to ask a question is to show what you have tried, describe what happens and explain what you expected by giving a complete minimal example.

Comment: Suggestion: first try to get all classes, next think how you would separate only those that are in non-`rdf:type` triples, then select only the subjects (distinct), and count that.